# Obtener una fecha con una frecuencia determinada

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

necesito de su ayuda, tengo una fecha que es variable, a esa fecha le sumará una frecuencia ejemplo **15 dias**, quisiera que a partir de la fecha dada ejemplo:
             **12/03/2018**
haga un conteo de su frecuncia establecida que pues
             **sumaria 15 dias**
y apartir de eso arrojaria la siguiente fecha la cual seria: 
             **27/03/2018**.
Y de igual forma quisiera que volviera hacer otra suma de otros **15 dias** y asi sucesivamente.
NOTA: estoy trabajando con php y javaScript

Comment: para estar claros, tu lo que quieres es sumar días a una fecha? eso es lo que no sabes?

Comment: El calculo lo quieres en php o javascript?

Comment: no exactemente, porque eso si se como, lo que yo quisiera es una idea para como hacer que esa suma se repita y me vuelda a dar la siguiente fecha y asi sucesivamente. @LPZadkiel

Comment: pues sinceramente le entiendo un pco mas a php, pero no sabira en cual este mas sencillo hacerlo. @IsmaelMartinez

Comment: Indica cuántas fechas necesitas o bien indica que vas a hacer con ellas para tener una idea más clara, por otro lado, escoge si lo manejaras por PHP o por JavaScript de otra forma la pregunta sería demasiado amplia. Lo de "cuál es mas sencillo hacerlo" es muy subjetivo.

Comment: pues me basaria al principio en 1 fecha de ahi partiria el conteo de la frecuencia, basado en eso quisiera que cada que se acompletara la frecuencia mandara una alerta

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para agregar a ella los detalles relevantes. También sería bueno que describieras brevemente lo que has buscado/investigado así como un [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca te dejo un ejemplo usando la librería [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/), y usando la función [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) de Javascript para crear la iteración  de la suma.

Como notaras puse un contador para que en algún momento termine la iteración y que no se ejecute eternamente.

```js
var fecha = moment("12/03/2018","DD/MM/YYYY");
var cont=0;

var loop = setInterval(function(){
  sumarDias()
  
  if(cont == 5)
    clearInterval(loop);
    
  cont++;
}, 1000);


function sumarDias(){
  fecha.add(15, 'days')
  console.log(fecha.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```